# Using WPF MediaElement for Multi-Track audio playback

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, audio, multiprocessing

I would like to work on a simple multi-track audio player using WPF (Framework 4.0) MediaElement. I'm more comfortable writing in VB than C#. Me doing C++ would be laughable.

What I've found is using 4 MediaElement instances I can playback the 4 discrete tracks without any problems on my 5 year old i7 2.8, 8GB RAM running Win7 computer. At 5 MediaElements and up, things go south.

My question, then is, would multithreading or multiprocessing allow me to achieve the results I'd like (all audio tracks playing in sync)?  Or am I simply asking too much of the .net framework and it's time for me to figure out how to do the playback in C++?

Thanks for any help as I try to wade through a new challenge.
Norm